# Running java issue on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I am a beginning java learner, and need to run my code in Eclipse. 
However I encountered below error:

> objc[4852]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Error: Could not
>   find or load main class

It looks like there are two path ways and Eclipse couldn't read the code/recognize the class.

Answer (score -1):

"Error: Could not find or load main class" This error usually means you don't have a main method on the Class your are trying to run.

I have personally had issues with having installed JREs twice. Remove the non-eclipse one and the problem may disappear.